# Composition of monotonic and measurable function is measurable

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am trying to find a counterexample since I think monotony is not enough.

Let $g:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be monotone and for all $n \in \mathbb{N}, f: \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ is measurable. Is $g \circ f$ and g measurable?

I know that a monotone function is measurable but I think for the composition $g$ must be continouous as well. What am I missing?

Comment: @StefanHansen Warning: When talking about Lebesgue-measurability, we consider different sigma-algebras on domain and codomain!

Comment: Please look at the definition of measurability. You can solve this exercise using **only** that definition and elementary properties of monotonous functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$g\circ f$ is measurable iff $(g\circ f)^{-1}\bigl((\alpha,\infty)\bigr)$ is measurable for al $\alpha$. By monotonicity of $g$, it is sufficient that $f$ is measurable.